# How to ignore python modules during import?

Tags: python, module

During the build process of a Python application I need to ignore some imports (because these modules are created by the build process). It is a chicken-and-egg-question, that I can't resolve easily.
So I thought I could use the import hook to do this like this:

```
class ImportBlocker(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.module_names = args

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if fullname in self.module_names:
            return self
        return None

    def load_module(self, name):
        raise ImportError("%s is blocked and cannot be imported" % name)

import sys
sys.meta_path = [ImportBlocker('chickenlib')]
```

But because I raise an error the build process stop --- I just want to silently ignore the import ... returning "None" does not work, too.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What sort of build process is this, and why does your build process have this (transitive? spurious?) dependency on modules that won't exist until the build process creates them?

Comment: Rather that trying to make Python ignore imports, it sounds like you should be cleaning up your dependency structure.

Comment: What does it mean to "silently ignore the import"? What is the exact effect that you are aiming for?

Comment: regarding the build process / import structure: the python module imports a C-Module, the glue-code is generated and the python module is loaded to examine it to create the glue-code. Then the C-Module is compiled. I want to ignore the import of the C-Module, because this is only used on runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working on Python 3.4 or greater than you can "silently ignore" an import by altering your example just slightly to implement an `exec_module` that will create an **empty** module.

```
class ImportBlocker(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.module_names = args

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if fullname in self.module_names:
            return self
        return None

    def exec_module(self, mdl):
        # return an empty namespace
        return {}
```

Now:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.meta_path = [ImportBlocker('chickenlib')]

>>> # this will work fine
>>> import chickenlib

>>> # there is nothing useful in your imported module
>>> print(vars(chickenlib))
{'__doc__': None, '__package__': '', '__name__': 'chickenlib', '__loader__': <__main__.ImportBlocker object at 0x102b8c470>, '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='chickenlib', loader=<__main__.ImportBlocker object at 0x102b8c470>)}
```

Comment: Oh ... thanks. I'll give it a try. For versions below Python 3.4 I could return an empty module nevertheless - I googled it, return ModuleType(name) might work, I check and report back ... Thanks.

Comment: @zet4080 On versions below 3.4, implement `load_module` to return an empty module but be careful to ensure all of the expected attributes are set (see documentation of `load_module`)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to "silently ignore the import", you can try this:

```
def TryImport(module_name):
    try:
        import module_name
    except ImportError:
        pass #or anything to log
```

Comment: `except ImportError` would be more specific.